# Expo app crashes only in Android when trying to navigate from a screen to the other using a Button

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-native-navigation

I created a stack navigator in react native and then used it from my home screen to go to the next screen using a button, when the button is clicked I am calling

```
props.navigation.navigate('SS2');
```

SS2 is the screen I want to go to.

This is working perfectly in iOS using the expo to run the app, however this is not the case for android, I have tried Android v8.0 and v9.0, in both of them expo crashed after the button was clicked.

There is no error message thrown at the expo server / terminal, the app just crashes and closes itself.

Here is the project which you can run and simulate the issue:

```
https://snack.expo.io/SkYyYFH5B
```

Here are the .js files I am using:

**package.json**:

```
   {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^7.0.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**App.js**:

```
import React from 'react';

import MainNavigator from './navigation/SingUpNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MainNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

**SingUpNavigator.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import LoginRegisterScreen from '../screens/LoginRegisterScreen';
import SS2 from '../screens/register/SS2';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: LoginRegisterScreen
      },
      LoginRegisterScreen: {
        screen: LoginRegisterScreen
      },
      SS2: {
        screen: SS2
      }
    },
    {
      headerMode: 'none'
    }
  )

  export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

**LoginRegisterScreen.js**:

```
 ... 
<MainButton title="REGISTER" onPress={() => { props.navigation.navigate('SS2')}}/>;
 ...
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on `https://expo.io`?

Comment: it's useful to follow this guide when posting questions: hhttps://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @nikolai-serg Yes, here is the link: https://snack.expo.io/SkYyYFH5B. When you click on Android the "REGISTER" button expo crashes, when you click it in iOS it works, it navigates to 'SS2' screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not caused by navigation and this has happened from `SS2` screen.

You should not use this `flex center` style like your code.

```
<View flex center style={styles.firstView}>

</View>
```

Instead of this style, you can use

```
style = {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

I updated your code. `https://snack.expo.io/@angelsinej/github.com-arditshala-seatr-demo:mobile`

Comment: Hi, i have a question concerning the above, so basically using their initial isnt this supposed to print out an error?

Comment: I had a similar issue and the app was crashing because of the style.. interesting